# how to call a post method api gateway using lib 'com.amazonaws.services.apigateway.model.*'

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

```
// Set up AWS credentials
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");

// Set the AWS region
Regions region = Regions.US_EAST_1;
// Create an AWS client with the credentials
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds);

AmazonApiGateway apiGatewayClient = AmazonApiGatewayClient.builder()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .build();
//Create a request
UpdateMethodRequest request = new UpdateMethodRequest();
request.setHttpMethod("POST");
request.setRestApiId("restapi_id");
request.setResourceId("resource_id");
// Create a new IntegrationRequest
UpdateIntegrationRequest rq = new UpdateIntegrationRequest();
// Set the request body and i don't know set request body. Can you help me?
// Execute the request
try {
  UpdateMethodResult result = apiGatewayClient.updateMethod(request);
  System.out.println(result.getMethodIntegration().getIntegrationResponses());
}catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

> i don't know set request body, can you help me?
>
> when i call a post api not set request body then return success but when i configure my api have request body and call my api by java then i don't find method set request body.